# Can Docker containers can be joined under one accessible hostname?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I started to develop with Laravel and since version 8, the Laravel development environment is shipped with docker and a tool named Sail (docker-compose).

When I configure my `.env` file I need to SSH the MySQL container and get its hostname, and then SSH the Mailhog container and do the same.
Besides the above when I want to see the database from a tool like TablePlus, I couldn’t make it access the MySQL container by hostname.

I did some searches and found that I can add the `hostname` directive, but I'm not sure if it's not disturbing the internal container's communication.

Can I use the `hostname` directive safety in my case? is there a way to join the containers under one hostname and make it accessible from my host?

I'm running Docker Desktop for a MAC - v20.10.2
The `docker-compose` for reference

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            # - pgsql
            - redis
            # - selenium
    # selenium:
    #     image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
    #     volumes:
    #         - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
    #     networks:
    #         - sail
    mysql:
        hostname: 'beatsy-db'
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping"]
#    pgsql:
#        image: postgres:13
#        ports:
#            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-5432}:5432'
#        environment:
#            PGPASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
#            POSTGRES_DB: '${DB_DATABASE}'
#            POSTGRES_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
#            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
#        volumes:
#            - 'sailpostgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
#        networks:
#            - sail
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
    # memcached:
    #     image: 'memcached:alpine'
    #     ports:
    #         - '11211:11211'
    #     networks:
    #         - sail
    mailhog:
        hostname: 'beatsy-mail'
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
#    sailpostgresql:
#        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
```

Comment: `hostname:` does almost nothing.  It's the equivalent of running, say, `sudo hostname stackoverflow.com` on your host system: it changes what the container thinks its own name is, but doesn't affect how anything else connects to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have several services in your `docker-compose.yml`:

- laravel.test
- mysql
- redis

and so on. Each of these is a resolavble name for containers in the same network. So instead of using mysql container hostname use its service name (just `mysql` in your case). You shouldn't use container hostnames because they're randomly generated.

Comment: I swear I did try to use the service name and it didn't work and now it's working.
Do you know how I can make the container accessible so tools like TablePlus (MySQL client) can access it?

Comment: @Yehuda Look at the container `ports` configuration, this is port forwarding rules. Left value is the port on host, right one is the port on container. So to access mysql with a tool from host you need to connect to `localhost:${FORWARD_DB_PORT}` (3306 if that variable is not set).